# Why happens this weird compiler behaviour in Android Studio 3.6?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I've updated for *Android Studio 3.6* today (`#AI-192.7142.36.36.6200805`, built on February 12, 2020). I use *Kotlin* (my version - `1.3.61` - is updated). My *Gradle* version is `5.6.4`(the last one).

A very strange stuff is happening for me.

The first problem is that now I need to press save icon (`^s`) before running. Until *Android 3.5* was automatic. But it's Ok, it is a matter of getting used to it.

The second problem is worst. I have a *typealias* that was *ArrayList* and I needed change to a simple *Array*, so I've changed the previous code `typealias Duo = ArrayList<Double>`  for `typealias Duo = Array<Double>`.

It's a big project, and I have in some module a small piece of code, that can be shown as

```
var gData = ArrayList<Duo>()    
gData.add(arrayOf(5.0, 1.0))
```

after I've saved the files (`^s`) and run.

Now appears the below error message pointing to the second line, even if the editor don't show a red mark in the code:

```
Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is Array<Double>
 but Duo /* = ArrayList<Double> */ was expected
```

I have no clue what is happening.... I've tried to `restart` and `restart and invalidate caches`, with no success. The same messages. I use  `find in path` (`^+f`) to check duplicate declarations of `duo`. Nope.

When I've tried the below toy code in [Kotlin Playground](https://play.kotlinlang.org/), it's OK. No error.

```
typealias Duo = Array<Double>
fun main() {
    var gData = ArrayList<Duo>()    
    gData.add(arrayOf(5.0, 1.0))
    println(gData[0][0])
}
```

I'm lost!

**UPDATE**

It should be a very serious bug in Android Studio 3.6. 
I've solved the problem, but it doesn't make any sense. I simply have replaced all 13 occurrences of `duo` with `dux` and the problem is over! (`Ctrl + Shift + R` - `Replace in Path`) After, I've switched back for `duo` (13 occurences) and the problem didn't return, but the mystery is on the air.

Comment: What happens if you now change it back? did you try to use File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart?

Comment: Yes, before change `duo` for `dux`,  I've tried to do `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart`.

Comment: Okay, so you said you changed `duo` to `dux` what happens if you now change it back to `Duo`, does the error occur again? Maybe try the following: Place your pointer on the `Duo` in this line `var gData = ArrayList<Duo>()` and press CTRL+B and see where it jumps. Does it jump to the definition of your Duo or maybe there is some other Kotlin-Class named Duo (though I couldn't find any in the documnetation so i don't think so)

Comment: I switched back from `dux` to `duo` and it worked. He made the 13 changes back. It has no logic.

Comment: Also I'm not sure if this is really an Android Studio problem, as the problem occurs on compilation and not in the IDE itself. Did you try to update to a newer version of Kotlin in your project?

Comment: Okay, this is weird, but at least it is fixed now.

Comment: I will check it. I've changed the Android Studio version one hour ago...